# How do I create an array of ifstream objects and how can I populate that array with numbered text files?

Tags: c++, file, io, ifstream

I have a bunch of text files in a directory, and each text file is named "info1.txt", "info2.txt" and so on. How would I open up all of the text files in an array of ifstream objects without having to hard-code all my text file names in? I know the following code does not work, but I think it conveys the idea of what I want to do if it did work:

```
ifstream myFiles[5];
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    myFiles[i].open("info" + i + ".txt");
}
```

I know the solution is probably very simple, but after a lot of research, trial and error I still haven't figured it out. Thanks!

Comment: you can search for all files that are inside  a specific folder , take there name and use it to create youre ifstream array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, I guess, the part about dynamically creating the file name.

One of the simple solutions is to use [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) to do it:

```
ifstream myFiles[5];
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    ostringstream filename;
    filename << "info" << i ".txt";
    myFiles[i].open(filename.str());
}
```

If your library is to old for it to accept `std::string` arguments in the call to `open` then use

```
    myFiles[i].open(filename.str().c_str());
```

Answer (score 8):

For building the file names, I'd use `std::ostringstream` and `operator<<`.

If you want to use a container class like `std::vector` (e.g. because you don't know at compile time how much big the array of `ifstream`'s will be), since `std::ifstream` is *not* copyable, you can't use `vector<ifstream>`, but you can use `vector<shared_ptr<ifstream>>` or `vector<unique_ptr<ifstream>>`; e.g.:

```
vector<shared_ptr<ifstream>> myFiles;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    ostringstream filename;
    filename << "info" << i << ".txt";
    myFiles.push_back( make_shared<ifstream>( filename.str() ) );        
}
```

With `unique_ptr` (and C++11 move semantics):

```
vector<unique_ptr<ifstream>> myFiles;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    ostringstream filename;
    filename << "info" << i << ".txt";
    unique_ptr<ifstream> file( new ifstream(filename.str()) );
    myFiles.push_back( move(file) );
}
```

`unqiue_ptr` is more efficient than `shared_ptr`, since `unique_ptr` is just a *movable* pointer, it's not reference counted (so there is less overhead than `shared_ptr`). So, in C++11, you may want to prefer `unique_ptr` if the `ifstream`'s are not shared outside the `vector` container.

Answer (score 3):

Your idea should work with a small change:

```
myFiles[i].open((std::string("info") + itoa(i) + ".txt").c_str());
             // ^^^^^^^^^^^           ^^^^
```

Also note that, you cannot use `std::vector` because `ifstream` is not a copyable object. So continue using the array.

Comment: He could use `vector<unique_ptr<ifstream>>` or `vector<shared_ptr<ifstream>>`.

Comment: Thanks for that! Is there a #include item that I need to use itoa though? I have a few thing included but when I compile I get an error that itoa isn't declared in the scope.

Comment: The array will only work if the number of files is known at compile time. If it varies at runtime he will need a dynamic collection. vector<shared_ptr<ifstream> > will work (or unique_ptr if available)

Answer (score 1):

I usually use std::stringstream:

```
{
  std::stringstream filename;
  filename << "info" << i << ".txt" << std::ends;
  myFiles[i].open(filename.str().c_str());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have an array of ifstream objects, but if you need a dynamic length, then you cannot do it this way, nor will `std::vector<ifstream>` work.

So you will need pointers. `std::vector<ifstream*>` will work but you might use shared_ptr so `std::vector<shared_ptr<ifstream> >` will work. If you have `unique_ptr` available you can use that instead of `shared_ptr`.

Each element will then have to be created with `new`.

You will also need to create the string properly, you can use a `boost::format` or `ostringstream` or even an old-fashioned `sprintf` to do that.

By the way, I would search boost's filesystem library to see if they have a more dynamic `ifstream` that can go happily in your vector without the messiness of shared_ptr.